# need to collect each property values in an array of objects to separate arrays

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I need to collect each property values in an array of objects int to separate property arrays, is there any simple way to do it. Either underscore and angularjs utilities are fine.

For example, I have an array of objects as,

```
 $scope.expNumArray = [];
 $scope.itemHrArray = []; 
 $scope.highReArray = [];

$scope.rowdata = [{
    "expNum": "678",    
    "itemHr": "",   
    "highRe": "C"
    }, {
    "expNum": "978",    
    "itemHr": "3",  
    "highRe": ""
}];
```

Now for this I need to have the following:

```
 $scope.expNumArray = ["678", "978"];

 $scope.itemHrArray = ["", "3"];

 $scope.highReArray = ["C",""];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use angular's `forEach` to achieve this.

```
$scope.expNumArray = [];
 $scope.itemHrArray = []; 
 $scope.highReArray = [];



$scope.rowdata = [{
    "expNum": "678",    
    "itemHr": "",   
    "highRe": "C"
    }, {
    "expNum": "978",    
    "itemHr": "3",  
    "highRe": ""
}];

angular.forEach($scope.rowdata,function(value,key){

   $scope.expNumArray.push(value["expNum"]);
   $scope.itemHrArray.push(value["itemHr"]);
   $scope.highReArray.push(value["highRe"]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore's each function to loop over

```
 $scope.rowdata
```

and append to each of the three other arrays.  A bit cleaner than a Javascript for loop.  [This article](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/06/stop-writing-for-loops-start-using-underscorejs/) about leveraging underscore might be of interest as well.